# how stop spam user registration in buddypress and wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using wordpress and buddypress in my website. I wants new user registration feature in website,But i found that there a large number of registration is going on in website,there are 2 or 3 user are getting register in every minute. I also use captcha for stopping spam registration, still this spam registration is going on.

Is there any backdoor entry in database or it is an buddypress issue?
How i can fix this ? Your help will really appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this plugins review](http://wpmu.org/buddypress-spam/) by WPMU team

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with this yet as it is still on my todo list, but I was looking at implementing http://www.spambotsecurity.com/zbblock.php to prevent similar irritating behaviour on a forum I was hosting. I see it supports Wordpress - and perhaps can be made to work with other php code. I found basic captcha codes to be ineffective, although I have not investigated some of the more recent developments.